# Pandas itertuples first row returns true even if match isnt found

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have 2 csv files with exact same rows as below:

> asas,asafdfdd,fgffgdvnufg,rterrtrrtr,wewewtyuhe,yuuiiyuyuy,uiuiui9u
>   absas,a2assafdfdd,fgffgedkfg,rtdfrtrrtr,wewewuikjhe,yuuiuiyouyuy,ui7u8iuiu
>   asbas,asasdfdfdd,fgffgfpoftg,rtrjktrrtr,wewewuyihe,yuyuyyupuy,uiu7iuiu
>   asabs,asafddffdd,fgffg2floig,rtrtrcxcrtr,weweyjunwe,yuyuyumy,uiui6uiu
>   asasbb,asafddfdd,fgffgdfkfg,rtrtrjkhrtr,wewewdfxe,yuyuyuny,uiui5uiu
>   absbas,asafdrtfdd,fgffgvbfg,rtrt3rrcxvtr,wewedfcwe,yuycuyuy,uiu4iuiu

I read these 2 csv files in 2 dataframes named df1 and df2 respectively. When I do `result = (df1==df2)`, I get another dataframe in results having True/False values for match (In this case True for all).

Now when with below code the first row is displayed even if there isnt 'False' value in that tuple.

```
for row in result.itertuples():    
    if(False in row):        
        print (row)
```

Why is this? Do i need to do something different here?

Whole code is here for reference:

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.read_csv('test3.csv',  header=None)
df2 = pd.read_csv('test4.csv', header=None)

result = (df1==df2)
print result
for row in result.itertuples():
    if(False in row):
        print (row)
```

Comment: I dont see any relevance of your question @jezrael here but AFAIK it `dataframeObject.head()` gives you top 5 rows, and `dataframeObject.tail()` gives you bottom 5 rows.

Comment: If you do  `print result` it will display all the rows (in this case with all values True).
Now, what I wan to do is print row which has value `False` in it with `if(False in row)`. As there isnt any row with value False in my example, I'm not expecting any row to print out; however the first row with all True values is getting printed which I'm not able to understand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because the first row has a zero in it.  So `False in [0]` is True.  This happens because the first index Value is zero.

if you shift your index values

```
result.index += 1
```

Then run your loop... it won't print.

---

Now this explains why this happens.  But I wouldn't do whatever your doing this way.

I'd do

```
for i, row in result.iterrows():
    if not row.all():
        print(row)
```

Comment: Or, if you don' need the index, `for row in df.itertuples(index=False)`.

Comment: Perfect this is what I wanted. Thank you so much :-)